# Using MongoDB on Heroku

Tags: python, mongodb, heroku

I created a Python webapp using Dash and deployed it to Heroku. This app should connect to a MongoDB database, but i'm having some problems setting this up. I made some research and i've been told to use MLab, but MLab had been bought by MongoDB, so everyone will need to use Atlas. I'm having some problems connecting this app to a database, but i don't know how to do that: should i only connect it to my Atlas Cloud? Are there other steps?

Comment: You just need to create DB in MLab, then get database url, database user and password and use it in your project. No need to use Atlas.

Comment: @SergeyPugach MLab had been bought by MongoDB, as a result everyone using MLab will need to migrate to Atlas

Comment: What are the exact problems are you having in connecting to Atlas ? It would be great to post example connection code, and also any error messages that you're seeing.

Answer (score 1):

I mean your problem is that your app at Heroku can't connect Mongo DB at Atlas.

**So, What I think might solve your problem**

- Currently, Heroku dynos use a subset of IP range of AWS EC2 instances, one can add the AWS IP ranges to the Cloud Atlas' whitelist. You can do that by following the [Guide on Heroku Dev Center](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mongolab)
- Or (Just for test) on the Mongo Db Atlas's IP Whitelist, you can add an IP Address with value as 0.0.0.0/0